# Prevent "Location Found" Notification

Tags: notifications, location-services

I have a Samsung Galaxy S7 (SM-G930V) through Verizon.  Every once in a while an app will request the phone's location.  The notification area will then display `Location Found`.

When I long-press on the `Location found` notification, I get the `App notifications` screen for `System UI`.  I don't think it would be wise if I disabled notifications for `System UI`.  It seems like this would block other useful notifications.

I could uninstall or disable the apps which are using `Location Services` and hence triggering the `Location found` notification.  However, I want the apps to run and use `Location Service`

How do I keep the `Location found` notification from appearing even though I am using the `Location Service`?

Answer (score 3):

Using an app such as [Automate](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.llamalab.automate), one can write a very simple flow which waits for notifications from `com.android.systemui` with the text of `Location found` and then cancel the notification as soon as it exists.

This works okay.  The flow doesn't use any CPU time until a notification shows up and then the flow is very quick (3 ms execution time).  However, the notification still appears for a brief moment.  My point is that this solution is like putting a net at the bottom of a cliff when a fence at the top would work much better.

Comment: This works, but results in an "Automate running" notification instead...

Answer (score 0):

Go to your location settings and change it from 'High Accuracy' to 'Battery Saver' to get rid of this "Location Found" notification. You can switch back to "High Accuracy" mode while using an app like Google Maps that needs your exact location.

Comment: Let me try this for a week and see how my apps do.

Comment: This answer kind of works.  As soon as I use `Google Maps`, then `Google Maps` will ask to switch to `High Accuracy`.  After I am done using `Google Maps`, I then have to manually switch back to `Battery Saver`.  Yuck.